# How to execute join query with another group by select statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

> I am executing two queries first for inner join to get data from table
>   and second group by query to get the sum.
>
> But is there any way to execute two queries in one query?
>
> First query:
>
> ```
> SELECT e.name,Value,address FROM table1 e  JOIN table2 p  ON p.name = e.name;
> ```

```
+--------+---------+------+----+
| name   |   Value | address   |
+--------+---------+------+----+
| name1  | 124     | address1  |
| name2  | 12      | address2  |
| name3  | 123     | address3  |
| name2  | 15      | address2  | 
+-------------+---------+------+
```

> Second query :
>
> ```
> SELECT name
>      , SUM(Value) Total 
>   FROM table1 
>  GROUP BY name;
> ```

```
+-------------+-------+
| name        | Total |
+-------------+-------+
| name3       |   123 |
| name2       |    27 |
| name1       |   124 |
+-------------+-------+
```

> and what I want is a sum column against every name

```
+-------------+------------+
| name | sum   | address   | 
+-------------+------------+
| name1 |  124 |  address1 | 
| name2 |   12 |  address2 |
| name3 |  123 |  address3 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Is it SQLserver or MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
SELECT donation_entry.Person_name,B.Total,Receipt,Date,month,Year,print_year,Valu e,address 
FROM donation_entry 
JOIN profile ON donation_entry.Person_name = profile.Person_name
JOIN (select Person_name,sum(Value) as Total from donation_entry group by Person_name)B on B.Person_name=donation_entry;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `SUM` aggregate to `value` column in your first query and add the
non aggregate in `Group by`

```
SELECT table1.name,
           Sum(Value),
           address
    FROM   table1
           JOIN table2
             ON table1.name = table2.name
    GROUP  BY table1.name,
              address
```

Considering `name` is unique in `table2` table